# Python - Is there a way to ask the same series of questions and store the each set of answers until the user is done?

Tags: python, loops, input

As a very new Python writer, I'm making a calculator that's supposed to ask the user a series of questions, and then determine an approximate total amount of money they've spent on chapstick throughout their life. I'm currently trying to loop a series of questions so that the answers can be used to calculate a total.

```
while brand != ''
   brand = str(input('Enter a brand of chapstick you use: '))
   brand = brand.title()
   brand_cost = float(input('How much does', brand, 'chapstick cost? $'))
   brand_quantity = int(input('How many', brand, 'chapstick(s) do you own? '))
   brand_regularly = int(input('How many', brand, 'chapsticks do you finish per year? '))
   brand_since = int(input('At what age did you first buy', brand, 'Chapstick? '))
```

Comment: I should also add that I know 'brand' is undefined in the first line of the sample. I just needed to make it clear that I want it defined multiple times also.

Comment: I think you need to do some reasearch by yourserlf before asking these questions. Please take a look to our guidelines on: [how to ask?](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=how+to+post+in+stack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append all the values to a list so that you can calculate them at the end when the use is done inputting his/her values. The code for this is shown below:

```
prices = []
quantity = []
per_year = []
since = []

while True:
    brand = str(input('Enter a brand of chapstick you use: '))
    brand = brand.title()
    brand_cost = float(input('How much does ' + brand + ' chapstick cost? $'))
    brand_quantity = int(input('How many ' + brand + ' chapstick(s) do you own?'))
    brand_regularly = int(input('How many' + brand + ' chapsticks do you finish per year? '))
    brand_since = int(input('At what age did you first buy' + brand + 'Chapstick? '))
    prices.append(brand_cost)
    quantity.append(brand_quantity)
    per_year.append(brand_regularly)
    since.append(brand_since)
    is_complete = str(input('Is that all (y/n)'))
    if is_complete == 'y':
        break
    elif is_complete == 'n'
        continue
```

After the user is done, you will have 4 lists containing all of the inputed values which you can use to do do your calculations.